# Issue with static variable at dll shutdown

Tags: c++, dll, com

I haven't tried it yet, but curious to know. Let's say we have a static object A in dll `D1`. `A` maintains reference to COM object `B` in dll `D2`. Is it possible that dll `D2` can unload even if `A` has reference to `B` in dll `D2`?

Comment: Where does the `shutdown` from the title figure in this picture?

Comment: This design is asking for trouble. First, chances are high `CoUninitialize` will be called some time before the shutdown sequence, and after that any COM call is suspect at best, including `IUnknown::Release`. Second, when the process terminates, DLLs are unloaded in arbitrary order, so yes, it's possible that `D2` is unloaded first. Third, you appear to envision doing non-trivial work in `DllMain` under loader lock (constructors and destructors of global objects in a DLL are effectively called from `DllMain`), which is a bad idea in itself.